# for loop optimize in C

Tags: c, for-loop, optimization

I have to optimize below for loop code. How can I do? Any suggestion? I tried to do unrolling for loop but it did not changed anything. 
Thanks.

G is a matrix of graph (directed or undirected graph)
Code is below:

```
void col_convert(int dim, int *G)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < dim; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < dim; j++)
            G[j*dim+i] = G[j*dim+i] || G[i*dim+j];
}
```

**EDIT:**
Most common dimension is 8.

Comment: I guess you want to optimize for speed... Well, one thing would be to stop calculating  i*dim every time inside the inner loop by taking the calculation into the outer loop and assigning the value to the variable that will be used inside the inner loop.

Comment: Do you know what is the most common value of `dim`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I speeded up more 5.4 times than the raw code. Thank you for all.

This is the answer:

```
void col_convert(int dim, int *G)
{

      int i, j,dimj,dimi,nj,ni;

      for (i = 0; i <= dim-8; i +=8){
          ni = dim * i;
          for (j = 0; j < dim; j++)
          {
              nj = j * dim ;
              dimj = nj + i;
              dimi = ni + j;
              G[dimj] |= G[dimi];

              dimj += 1;
              dimi += dim;
              G[dimj] |= G[dimi];

              dimj += 1;
              dimi += dim;
              G[dimj] |= G[dimi];

              dimj += 1;
              dimi += dim;
              G[dimj] |= G[dimi];

              dimj += 1;
              dimi += dim;
              G[dimj] |= G[dimi];

              dimj += 1;
              dimi += dim;
              G[dimj] |= G[dimi];

              dimj += 1;
              dimi += dim;
              G[dimj] |= G[dimi];

              dimj += 1;
              dimi += dim;
              G[dimj] |= G[dimi];
          }
      }

      // Use the normal loop for any remaining elements
      for (; i < dim; i++){
        ni = i * dim;

          for (j = 0; j < dim; j++){
            nj = j * dim;
            dimj = nj + i;
            dimi = ni + j;
            G[dimj] |= G[dimi];
          }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can halve the number of iterations by noticing that the operation is symmetric:

```
void naive_col_convert(int dim, int *G) {
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        G[i * dim + i] = G[i * dim + i] != 0;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < dim; j++) {
            G[i * dim + j] = G[j * dim + i] = G[j * dim + i] || G[i * dim + j];
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** if the most common value is 8, try the code below with `-O3`.  The compiler should be able to generate efficient code for the special case from the same source code.

```
void naive_col_convert(int dim, int *G) {
    if (dim == 8) {
    #define dim 8
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
            G[i * dim + i] = G[i * dim + i] != 0;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < dim; j++) {
                G[i * dim + j] = G[j * dim + i] = G[j * dim + i] || G[i * dim + j];
            }
        }
    #undef dim
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
            G[i * dim + i] = G[i * dim + i] != 0;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < dim; j++) {
                G[i * dim + j] = G[j * dim + i] = G[j * dim + i] || G[i * dim + j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the performance improvement is not significant, you can unroll the loops by hand onto a sequence of 36 statements.  Reordering these statements may yield additional improvements for selected architectures and slower operation on others.

Comment: Your code is faster than above code by 2.3 times. What can we do to speed up? Cache blocking?

Comment: @SevkiBekir: Do you know what is the most common value of `dim`? If the code is used mostly for a fixed value of `dim`, special casing this value will allow the compiler to unroll the loops and remove most multiplications.

Comment: Most common value is 8.

Comment: @SevkiBekir: I updated the answer with some extra ideas, try and see if you get improved performance.

Comment: Thank you for help!